# How to acces Accessing alternate Columns of a Array/Data frame?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix **A** of dimension say **1896x1600** Now i want to sub-sample this matrix in such a way that I get a new matrix **B** of dimension 1896x800 but instead of random sampling,I want the values from columns like first 100 columns and skipping the next 100 columns, i.e columns 1-100, 201-300, 401-500...1401-1500 so that I am trying to take alternate 100 columns from the matrix so that I would get a matrix **B** of dimension **1896x800**. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You can easily do it throgh indexing. Ref.to the on-line documentation: [here](https://it.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), or [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html), just to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job-

```
in=1:size(A,2); % column indices
B1=A(:,mod(floor((in-1)/100),2)==0); % for columns 1-100,201-300,...
B2=A(:,mod(floor((in-1)/100),2)==1); % for columns 101-200,301-400,...
```

Comment: You are most welcome! But I'd suggest that you do a little bit more of reading and try to understand the logic behind the processes. It would help you to solve the problems with much ease!

Comment: Yes Rahul!! I will do that. Thank you.